# Django Rest Framework allow not authenticated access to a view in certain cases

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a **ViewSet** which `permission_classes` is set to `(permissions.IsAuthenticated,)`, but I want this view to allow not authenticated access when the method is `retrieve()`.

This is my **ViewSet**:

```
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = proxies.AlbumProxy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AlbumSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'description', 'company__name')
    filter_fields = ('code', 'company')

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        password = request.query_params.get('password', None)

        instance = proxies.AlbumProxy.objects.get(code=pk)

        if instance.access_code != password and password != settings.MASTER_KEY:
            raise Exception(_("Invalid password for album {}".format(instance.code)))

        instance_to_return = serializers.AlbumSerializer(instance=instance, context={'request': request}).data
        instance_to_return.pop('access_code')

        return Response(instance_to_return)
```

Is there a way I can disable `permission_classes` when the method `retrieve()` is on, but to leave it working in any other case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override get_permissions like so:

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action == 'retrieve':
        return []  # This method should return iterable of permissions
    return super().get_permissions()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Django Rest Framework` gives what you need out of the box. See [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly).